# Windows - read last line of text file, find word/phrase perform action

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

I am trying to do the following:

I have a file of which i am trying to read and if a certain phrase is found in the very last line, i want to perform an action.

This is the last few lines of the the text file

A PC is either going to have the above in the log file repeated over and over or it will not have anything close.

I essentially want to read the very last line and see if it finds "Failed to get registration state" and if it does run a script.

Here is what i have so far but i think i am nowhere near what i should be doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i am not very good at scripting. I was basically trying to count the number of lines and store it in a variable:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\Client.log') do set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /i "Failed to get registration state. Error" more /e +%startLine% C:\Client.log') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Client.log) do set "line=%%a"
echo "%line%"|findstr /i /c:"Failed to get registration state. Error" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo not found
) else (
 echo found
)
```

`line` will be set to the contents of each line in turn. When the `for` loop ends, it will contain the contents of the last line. Then test for the string, but since it contains spaces, you need `/c:` otherwise it would find **any** of the words in the quoted-string.

[edit : added `@echo off` line and inserted quotes around `%line%` in piped-echo.]

Since your target line appears to include redirectors, the quotes are required.

I conclude from your comments that your last line may be

```
<![LOG[RegTask: Failed to get registration state. Error: 0x8009000b]LOG]!>
```

Regrettably, you haven't posted examples, not have you edited your question to add-in your code so the precise layout of the code you are using (which is critical) remains a mystery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So i have run what you posted but it prints every line to screen and doesn't display "not found" or "Found". Am i doing something wrong with it?

Comment: Batch syntax is quirky - best to cut-and-paste (and add your own `@echo off`) If it's printing each line, then the `echo` statement in the second line is working, which means the `findstr` may be failing. Possibly the pipe (`|`) is missing or you've decided to put the `findstr` on a second line. The code must be run as-is. It's almost impossible for the final `if` to fail - there's no explanation of that. Edit your question to add your current code in by cutting-and pasting.

Comment: this is whats confusing me. I have even tried this and it doesnt even get to the pause line:                                                                                                  
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\Client.log) do set "line=%%a"
echo %line%|findstr /i /c:"Failed to get"
pause                                                                                 
This is the last line it displays
echo <![LOG[RegTask: Failed to get registration state. Error: 0x8009000b]LOG]!>|findstr /i /c:"Failed to get"

Comment: would it matter that when i am running scripts i see this in the output: 
< was unexpected at this time

I was messing around with this and your script does the same thing as well with the '< was unexpected..' and it doesnt get to the pause

for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\ClientIlog') do set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines% - 1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('more /e +%startLine% C:\Client.log') DO Set logline=%%A
echo %logline%
pause

Comment: ok i think i may have something that will work. It might be an elegant solution but it seems to work for what i need it to do. Open to sugesstions

`set keyword=failed
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\Client.log') do set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines% - 1
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%A IN ('more /e +%startLine% C:\Client.log') DO Set logline=%%A
echo %logline%
IF /I %keyword%==%logline% (echo found) else (echo not found)`

Comment: thanks for your help. first time posting on here sorry for the gaps in the info provided. Can i mark both provided solutions as answered?

Comment: No - sadly, only one solution can be selected as the `preferred response` - but it's also possible to upvote any solution by pressing the up-arrow above the score to the left of the posting. Equally, you can downvote - but really only legitimate to use when a solution is bad advice rather than unpopular or just didn't solve the problem. (It could be you need a minimum reputation score to up/downvote (so long ago...) and also be warned - a downvote **costs** the voter reputation. Also polite to explain a downvote and to reverse it if you get a satisfactory explanation/refutation/correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the number of last line
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\Client.log') do set "lastLine=%%i"

rem Get the number of last line where target string was found
for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ('find /N /i "Failed to get registration state. Error" C:\Client.log') do set "lastFound=%%a"

if "%lastFound%" equ "%lastLine%" echo Run the script
```

Comment: thanks. Your script seems to just give me the line number. I dont know how many lines the log file will have, thats why i need to find the string

Comment: Ops! I forgot to include the `/N` switch in find command! Please, copy the code again and test it...

Comment: You've also omitted the `/c:` switch. Without it, you'll target each individual word in the quotes, not the complete string in the quotes.

Comment: @Magoo: Err, no... You are referring to `findstr` command, but I am using `find` instead! However, such error appears in the OP´s example code. Why you didn't posted such comment below the original question since the very beginning (23 hours ago)? **`:/`**

Comment: thanks for your help. first time posting on here sorry for the gaps in the info provided

Comment: Yes - so you are. Probably had `findstr` on the brain. Or lack of caffeine. So many possibilities! I'm puzzled why OP can't get my version working (it works fine for me.) It should work faster since it only scans the source file once. Ah well - in computing, there are many paths to a solution.